# How to extract value from xml file using grep

Tags: xml, bash, sed, grep

I have a XML file as follow

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<coverage branch-rate="0" branches-covered="0" branches-valid="0" complexity="0" line-rate="0.7606" lines-covered="270" lines-valid="355" timestamp="1595999208833" version="5.2.1">
    <!-- Generated by coverage.py: https://coverage.readthedocs.io -->
    <!-- Based on https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cobertura/web/master/htdocs/xml/coverage-04.dtd -->
    <sources>
        <source>/home/lebanon/appt</source>
    </sources>
    <packages>
        <package branch-rate="0" complexity="0" line-rate="1" name="application">
            <classes>
                <class branch-rate="0" complexity="0" filename="application/__init__.py" line-rate="1" name="__init__.py">
                    <methods/>
                    <lines>
                        <line hits="1" number="23"/>
                    </lines>
                </class>
            </classes>
        </package>
</coverage>
```

I want to retrieve line-rate value inside the  tag.
How can this be achieved using grep ?

Comment: IMHO experts always advice to use tools like xmlstarlet, xmlint for dealing with xml files. Because they understand xmls well. So please do let us know if you have these tools available in your system? If not could you please get them? Because depending upon that only we may receive answers, cheers.

Comment: Also on SO users are advised to do add their efforts which they have put in order to solve their own problems, so kindly do add the same in your question and let us know then.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/12957340

Comment: `grep -oP '<coverage.*line-rate=\K"0.[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]"' coverage.xml` I used this command, i get output "0.7606". How do i remove the quotes?

Comment: See `man tr`. It has an option for removing characters.

Answer (score 2):

You should not parse xml with grep (although you can), so with `xmllint` you can do this

```
xmllint --xpath '/coverage/@line-rate' file.xml
```